# Как подключить In-app Billing для своего приложения?

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

Как добавить покупки в приложение? Как это вообще будет осуществляться? Нужен ли собственный бэкэнд? Есть ли хорошие гайды на русском? Какие библиотеки для покупок вы бы могли посоветовать?

Если кто-нибудь может, необходимо расписать пошагово внедрение покупок в приложении. Заранее спасибо!

(Просто за 2 недели необходимо правильно внедрить покупки)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучшей, таковой либой по in-app-billing, я считаю (IMHO, конечно) либу [android-inapp-billing-v3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) в написании коей я принимал скромное участие :)

Как использовать - в README проекта все расписано.

Comment: Спасибо, а с безопасностью там все в порядке? Правильно я понимаю, что для того, чтобы настроить эту либу, необходимо добавить разрешение в манифест, зависимость в градл и вставить лицензионный ключ из плей маркета?

Comment: Да, там все в порядке - вставляете свой ключ, пермишены и вперед.

Comment: Подтверждаю! Либа супер! Сам ее использую. Раз-два и все готово! :-) Благодарю ее авторов за труд!